# replacing a string with multiple lines in many files

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I'm using the code bellow, and can't seem to get searchterm to match a string with multiple lines.

```
!/bin/bash
# **************** Change Variables Here ************
startdirectory="/home/www"
searchterm="<img src=\"index.gif\">
<p>Hello World</p>
"
replaceterm="Hi"
# **********************************************************

i=0; 

  for file in $(grep -l -R $searchterm $startdirectory)
    do
      cp $file $file.bak
      sed -e "s/$searchterm/$replaceterm/ig" $file > tempfile.tmp
      mv tempfile.tmp $file

    let i++;

      echo "Modified: " $file
    done

echo " *** All Done! *** Modified files:" $i
```

Comment: `sed` primarily works one line at a time. Searching over multiple lines is possible, but hard enough work that you don't normally do it. You need to migrate to a more powerful language — probably Perl or Python. You probably could do it in `awk`; it would be simpler than `sed` but harder than Perl or Python.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you'd do it with bash and Perl:

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob
cd $searchdirectory
perl -0777 -i.bak -pe "s/$searchterm/$replaceterm/g" **
```

The `-0777` option for perl reads the files whole, not line-by-line. Then the pattern match can work over the entire file at once. I assume your files are not enormous.
I also assume you don't have any filenames with spaces or newlines.

Note that will touch *every* file. You can sweep the directory afterward to remove any `file.bak` that is unchanged from `file`.